# How to add hard coded user details to ngx admin login page

Tags: angular

i recently cloned the ngx admin template. im trying to learn angular. what i want is to add a hard coded username and password for user login. if and only if that particular value is typed, the login should redirect to the dashboard. currently any email or password i type is being redirected to the dashboard page. please help.

login.component.js

```
    var __decorate = (this && this.__decorate) || function (decorators, target, key, desc) {
    var c = arguments.length, r = c < 3 ? target : desc === null ? desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key) : desc, d;
    if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.decorate === "function") r = Reflect.decorate(decorators, target, key, desc);
    else for (var i = decorators.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) if (d = decorators[i]) r = (c < 3 ? d(r) : c > 3 ? d(target, key, r) : d(target, key)) || r;
    return c > 3 && r && Object.defineProperty(target, key, r), r;
};
var __metadata = (this && this.__metadata) || function (k, v) {
    if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.metadata === "function") return Reflect.metadata(k, v);
};
var __param = (this && this.__param) || function (paramIndex, decorator) {
    return function (target, key) { decorator(target, key, paramIndex); }
};
/**
 * @license
 * Copyright Akveo. All Rights Reserved.
 * Licensed under the MIT License. See License.txt in the project root for license information.
 */
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { NB_AUTH_OPTIONS_TOKEN } from '../../auth.options';
import { getDeepFromObject } from '../../helpers';
import { NbAuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
var NbLoginComponent = (function () {
    function NbLoginComponent(service, config, router) {
        if (config === void 0) { config = {}; }
        this.service = service;
        this.config = config;
        this.router = router;
        this.redirectDelay = 0;
        this.showMessages = {};
        this.provider = '';
        this.errors = [];
        this.messages = [];
        this.user = {};
        this.submitted = false;
        this.redirectDelay = this.getConfigValue('forms.login.redirectDelay');
        this.showMessages = this.getConfigValue('forms.login.showMessages');
        this.provider = this.getConfigValue('forms.login.provider');
    }
    NbLoginComponent.prototype.login = function () {
        var _this = this;
        this.errors = this.messages = [];
        this.submitted = true;
        this.service.authenticate(this.provider, this.user).subscribe(function (result) {
            _this.submitted = false;
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                _this.messages = result.getMessages();
            }
            else {
                _this.errors = result.getErrors();
            }
            var redirect = result.getRedirect();
            if (redirect) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    return _this.router.navigateByUrl('pages/dashboard');
                }, _this.redirectDelay);
            }
        });
    };
    NbLoginComponent.prototype.getConfigValue = function (key) {
        return getDeepFromObject(this.config, key, null);
    };
    return NbLoginComponent;
}());
NbLoginComponent = __decorate([
    Component({
        selector: 'nb-login',
        template: "\n    <nb-auth-block>\n      <h2 class=\"title\">Log In</h2>\n      <small class=\"form-text sub-title\">Hello! Log in with your email</small>\n\n      <form (ngSubmit)=\"login()\" #form=\"ngForm\" autocomplete=\"nope\">\n\n        <div *ngIf=\"showMessages.error && errors && errors.length > 0 && !submitted\"\n             class=\"alert alert-danger\" role=\"alert\">\n          <div><strong>Oh snap!</strong></div>\n          <div *ngFor=\"let error of errors\">{{ error }}</div>\n        </div>\n\n        <div *ngIf=\"showMessages.success && messages && messages.length > 0 && !submitted\"\n             class=\"alert alert-success\" role=\"alert\">\n          <div><strong>Hooray!</strong></div>\n          <div *ngFor=\"let message of messages\">{{ message }}</div>\n        </div>\n\n        <div class=\"form-group\">\n          <label for=\"input-email\" class=\"sr-only\">Email address</label>\n          <input name=\"email\" [(ngModel)]=\"user.email\" id=\"input-email\" pattern=\".+@.+..+\"\n                 class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"Email address\" #email=\"ngModel\"\n                 [class.form-control-danger]=\"email.invalid && email.touched\" autofocus\n                 [required]=\"getConfigValue('forms.validation.email.required')\">\n          <small class=\"form-text error\" *ngIf=\"email.invalid && email.touched && email.errors?.required\">\n            Email is required!\n          </small>\n          <small class=\"form-text error\"\n                 *ngIf=\"email.invalid && email.touched && email.errors?.pattern\">\n            Email should be the real one!\n          </small>\n        </div>\n\n        <div class=\"form-group\">\n          <label for=\"input-password\" class=\"sr-only\">Password</label>\n          <input name=\"password\" [(ngModel)]=\"user.password\" type=\"password\" id=\"input-password\"\n                 class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"Password\" #password=\"ngModel\"\n                 [class.form-control-danger]=\"password.invalid && password.touched\"\n                 [required]=\"getConfigValue('forms.validation.password.required')\"\n                 [minlength]=\"getConfigValue('forms.validation.password.minLength')\"\n                 [maxlength]=\"getConfigValue('forms.validation.password.maxLength')\">\n          <small class=\"form-text error\" *ngIf=\"password.invalid && password.touched && password.errors?.required\">\n            Password is required!\n          </small>\n          <small\n            class=\"form-text error\"\n            *ngIf=\"password.invalid && password.touched && (password.errors?.minlength || password.errors?.maxlength)\">\n            Password should contains\n            from {{ getConfigValue('forms.validation.password.minLength') }}\n            to {{ getConfigValue('forms.validation.password.maxLength') }}\n            characters\n          </small>\n        </div>\n\n        <div class=\"form-group accept-group col-sm-12\">\n                 </div>\n\n        <button [disabled]=\"submitted || !form.valid\" class=\"btn btn-block btn-hero-success\"\n                [class.btn-pulse]=\"submitted\">\n          Log In\n        </button>\n      </form>\n\n             <small class=\"form-text\">\n                 </small>\n       </nb-auth-block>\n  ",
    }),
    __param(1, Inject(NB_AUTH_OPTIONS_TOKEN)),
    __metadata("design:paramtypes", [NbAuthService, Object, Router])
], NbLoginComponent);
export { NbLoginComponent };
//# sourceMappingURL=login.component.js.map
```

Comment: please paste the ts files instead of compiled js files for better readability. Paste the login template and its component ts file.

Comment: This is an auto generated file which was already existing in node modules. There are no login template and component ts files. I thought of making my own component ts and template but I wanted to know whether ngx-admin already provides a method or not.

Comment: clone or fork the repo https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin dude , and edit for your needs .

Comment: I have already cloned the repository. There is no template for login template or component.ts for ng4. ng4 uses Nebular authentication as the login hence it only has a js file.

Comment: why not create your own login component? i also wanted to achieve the same as yours, so i create my own component, you can see my full code here https://github.com/naonvl/kewirus-dashboard/tree/master/src/app/auth